# SVG for src of <img> works for Angular CLI app, but not for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, image, svg

I have an SVG file that I use for the logo of an Angular CLI application.  I just put an `<img>` into the `app.component.html` in my `<header>` and it handles it just fine.

I'm doing a lunch and learn on Rails in about a week and I tried using the same logo for that, but I get the classic Chrome broken image icon instead of my svg displaying.

`Rails.application.assets.find_asset '<svg_name>.svg'` works and indicates that that svg is loaded into the asset pipeline just fine.

It's the same file, so the contents of the file shouldn't have to change.  I don't understand why one web application would be able to serve up the svg file and the other one can't.

Comment: You should post some code examples, just some snippets of how you're using `image_tag`. This is in a development environment, right?

Comment: And where did you place the svg file, in which folder?